# Two errors in a simple code, Invalid token '=' , a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#

I got two errors in my simple code. I googled but cann't find the answer. Seems something related with counstructor?

Here are errors:

Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.a' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

below is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int a = 1;
    a = 2; //I got errors after i wrote this line, cannot assign value?

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 1;
        a = 10;
        decimal myDecimalValue = 10;
        int myIntValue = (int) myDecimalValue;

        MessageBox.Show(myDecimalValue.ToString() );
    }

}
```

Seriously, can you tell me the reason for negative? 
My question is not clear? or forbidden to ask certain questions?? Before I asked this question, I gooled a lot web pages but no answer for it.

Comment: You need to add that in some method. perhaps constructor? Also is there a reason for not just doing `int a = 2;` directly?

Comment: a = 2; needs to be inside a function block.

Comment: You can only declare members at that level. Assigning new values to them needs to be done inside methods.

Comment: The error is too trivial and basic. Suggest visiting http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html for a refresher.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thanks, I am writing the code for testing, no special reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use assignment in a class definition if it is part of member initialization, as in `int a = 1;`, or in a method/constructor/property body, so if you want to assign a value right after initializing it, you'd have to put it in the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    a = 2;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not positive, but it looks like that line is not inside a method. If you are trying set it as 2, would it be beneficial to initialize it as 2?

Int a = 2